# Rails displaying table data dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Models

```
class Smoothval < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :smoothings
has_many :steps

end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :usdzar
belongs_to :smoothing
belongs_to :smoothval

default_scope lambda {
    order(id: :desc)
}

end

class Usdzar < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :smoothings
has_many :steps

end
```

The index view that I am trying to achieve:

```
<table><thead>
<tr>
<th>Smoothing1</th>
<th>Smoothing2</th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>"finalsmprice","stepnum"</td>
<td>"finalsmprice","stepnum"</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table
```

So all the fsmprices and the stepnums for every smoothval from the steps table

My index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<h1>Listing Steps</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>

<% Step.all.includes(:smoothval).group_by(&:smoothval_id).each do |smoothval_id, steps| %>
<tr>
<th>
Smoothing: <%= smoothval_id %>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% steps.each do |step| %>
 <tr>
 <td>
 (<%= step.fsmprice %>): <%= step.stepnum %>
  </td>


  <% end %>
 </tr> </tbody>
<% end %>

</table>
```

The table is very long and obviously displays all headings and data after one another. I have tried to create a postgres pivot table but that failed using tablefunc so back trying to do it in rails

In my controller I can get the smoothvals (the table headings) into an array as follows, the array looks like [1, 5]:

```
sv = Smoothval.where('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(steps.smoothval_id) FROM steps)')
@assigned = sv.pluck(:id)
```

How can I get the above table layout

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was too difficult and came accross a post that said its best to create a pivot table
HOWEVER thats not so easy in Postgres, the issue with the tablefunc extension is that it doesnt dynamically assign the columns, so they need to be statically assigned. So I went this route for now and tested the function https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot

I stuck with the basics and did this but will need to think more about refactoring the solution.

```
SELECT c_crosstab('Select * from steps', 'ct_view', 'id', 'smoothval_id', 'stepnum', 'first');

SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT usdzar_id, smoothval_id, stepnum
   FROM   steps
   ORDER  BY 1,2 ASC')  -- needs to be "ORDER BY 1,2" here
AS ct ("SV" int, "Smooth1" int, "Smooth2" int, "Smooth3" int);
```

Hope this helps somoene else